# Why is this GC system bad?

Tags: garbage-collection, language-features, compiler-theory

I have thought of a GC which I can't see major flaws with, and I am wondering why it isn't used more prevalently, or why I haven't heard of its use.

The system is:

- All objects have a 4 byte unsigned int counter attached to them. (Could be 2 bytes, I don't know.
- Whenever an object is constructed, its counter is started at 1.
- When an object is sent to a function as a parameter, its counter is incremented.
- When an object reaches the point where it is no longer used within a function (Could be the very end of scope) its counter is decremented.
- When the object's counter reaches zero, it is deleted, as at no position in code is it referenced.

Is there a fringe case in which the counter becomes faulty? What are the disadvantages, and the advantages?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its called [reference counting.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) I would suggest reading the wikipedia article as it covers the advantages and disadvantages.